# Finding the least square line passing through the origin

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares

So, I am trying to solve a least square problem. I have the matrix $$
 A= \begin{bmatrix}
\ 1&-1 \\ 1 & 1 \\ 1&2
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

and the matrix

$$ b = \begin{bmatrix} 
7 \\ 7 \\ 21
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Now, I have found the least square line normally with the equation being $$y(t) = 4x + 9$$. However, I know am trying to find a straight line through the origin that best fits the data in a least square sense. So, my thinking is $y(0) = m \cdot 0 + b = 0$. So I know b, must equal to zero, I wanna say that $m = \frac{21}{2}$ since both the 7's would be on either side. I got y(t) by using $A^t Ax = A^Tb$. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Algebraic Pavel provides an elegant solution. A less rigorous solution follows.

The function which forces the solution through the origin has the form $y(x) = ax$ where $a$ is the slope. With these data the sum of the squares of the residuals is
$$
r^2(a) = \Bigg\Vert
\left[
    \begin{array}{r}
      -1 \\
      1 \\
      2
    \end{array}
\right] 
\left[
    \begin{array}{r}
      a
    \end{array}
\right] 
-
\left[
    \begin{array}{r}
      7 \\
      7 \\
      21
    \end{array}
\right] \Bigg\Vert^{2}
$$

The problem reduces to finding the minimum of $r^2(a) = 6a^2 - 84 a + 539$, that is, solve
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial a} r^2 = 12 a - 84 = 0
$$

As shown earlier, the solution is that the slope $a = 7$.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to solve a *linear least squares problem with linear constraints*. The solution can be found by using Lagrange multipliers. Assume you want to solve $Ax=b$ (where $A$ has full column rank) in the least squares sense such that $Cx=d$ (where $C$ has full row rank). The Lagrange function of the problem is
$$
\mathcal{L}(x,\lambda)=\frac{1}{2}\|Ax-b\|_2^2+\lambda^T(Cx-d).
$$
Now compute the gradient w.r.t. $x$ and $\lambda$:
$$
\nabla_x\mathcal{L}(x,\lambda)=A^T(Ax-b)+C^T\lambda,
\quad
\nabla_{\lambda}\mathcal{L}(x,\lambda)=Cx-d.
$$
Hence the first order optimality conditions give you the system
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A^TA&C^T\\
C&0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\\lambda
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
A^Tb\\
d
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

---

Now plug in your $A$ and $b$, the linear constraint is $[1,0]x=0$ (you want the constant term of the line, which is the first component of $x$, to be zero), so $C=[1,0]$ and $d=0$. Solving the system leads to
$$
x=\begin{bmatrix}
   0\\7
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and thus 
$$
y(t)=7t.
$$

---

Yet another, less general but more straightforward, approach is to directly consider the line to have the form $y(t)=xt$. With
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\\2\end{bmatrix}
$$
you get the least squares problem $Ax=b$ (with the same $b$ as before).
Hence $x=(A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb=7$.